# How to get what mouse button was pressed in EventHandler?

Tags: user-interface, eventhandler

I'm trying to make an interface that (basically) records what mouse button was pressed inside the cell of a matrix.

The code I have so far is

```
A = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}];

DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, Dynamic@EventHandler[ArrayPlot[A],
   "MouseDown" :> (
     A[[
        Ceiling[10 - MousePosition["Graphics"][[2]]],
        Ceiling[MousePosition["Graphics"][[1]]]
      ]] = CurrentValue["MouseButtons"])]]
```

It kind of works, except that CurrentValue["MouseButtons"] seems to be returning strange things: it returns {1} for my left mouse button, empty set {} for my right mouse button, and nothing happens when I click my scrollwheel/middle mouse button. Why is that? Shouldn't I be getting something like 1 for left mouse, 2 for right mouse, and 3 for middle mouse buttons (at least according to the documentation)? My mouse seems to be working fine.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** A more streamlined version of the original post:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, 
 Dynamic@EventHandler[ ArrayPlot[A, ImageSize -> 300, DataReversed -> True],
   {"MouseDown", #} :> (A[[##&@@ (Ceiling/@Reverse[MousePosition["Graphics"]])]] = #)&/@
    {1, 2}]]
```

**Original post:**

```
A = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}];
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}},  Dynamic@EventHandler[
   Row[{ArrayPlot[A, ImageSize -> 300],  Style[MatrixForm[A], 16]}],
     {{"MouseDown",  1} :> (A[[Ceiling[10 - MousePosition["Graphics"][[2]]], 
         Ceiling[MousePosition["Graphics"][[1]]]]] = 1), 
      {"MouseDown",  2} :> (A[[Ceiling[10 - MousePosition["Graphics"][[2]]], 
         Ceiling[MousePosition["Graphics"][[1]]]]] = 2)}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I can't get the middle mouse button detected with EventHandler (Version 9 Windows 10).