# Disabling the "scroll when middle mouse button is pressed" functionality

Tags: dynamic, keyboard

(Mathematica 12.1 and Windows 10)

If the middle mouse button is kept pressed and the mouse is moved, Mathematica will scroll. Is it possible to disable this functionality?

I looked for mouse entries in `KeyEventTranslations.tr` but there are none. I also tried modifying the [`ScrollingOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScrollingOptions.html) in the Options Inspector, setting the max scrolling speed to 0, but it had no effect. Also checked some answers related to `ControllerInformation[]` from [What is the middle mouse button called in Mathematica's code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124836/34746), but no controllers appear for Windows, as remarked in those answers.

On Windows my middle mouse button is set to do a middle click, not scrolling, so I assume this scrolling behaviour comes from Mathematica itself.